# Yii serve AR with it's relations() through SOAP

Tags: activerecord, soap, yii, foreign-key-relationship

**MY QUESTION:**

What is the smartest way to expose through @soap a AR that has relations()? Is it possible to expose the related AR without manually assigning it to a public @soap member? Is it possible to link the relation name defined in the relations() with the @soap variable in some way?

Here is a looong background on what i was doing. I actually successfully shared the AR record with it's related AR records, but i think this is messy and want to ask if someone knows a more elegant way.

**BACKGROUND:**

I've successfully expose a AR record through soap by adding public variables annotated with @soap:

In Property Model :

```
 /** @soap @var integer */ public $id;
 /** @soap @var string */  public $street;
 /** @soap @var string */  public $city;
 /** @soap @var integer */ public $fk_state;
 /** @soap @var string */  public $property_title;
```

This works ok!

The next thing i want is to send the a related AR record as part of the request (want to add the state details, so first of all i added the relation expression in the Property model for the States model:

```
 /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        return array('STATE' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'State', 'fk_state'), );
    }
```

... add @soap variables to the State model too:

```
/** @soap @var integer */ public $id;
/** @soap @var string */  public $title;
/** @soap @var integer */ public $code;
```

Now i add a @soap public variable to the Property model to hold the related AR object:

```
 /** @soap @var State */   public  $_STATE;
```

this means that i want to send an object of type State through SOAP.

The last thing, before serving the data is to assign the related AR record of the STATE to the public @soap variable $_STATE:

```
$model->_STATE = State::model()->STATE; // assign related AR object to to the public @soap variable
```

**It's kind of messy because:**

1. need to do this $model->_STATE assignment all the time
2. it's redundant to have both the related AR called STATE and the public @soap variable $_STATE that hold basically the same info

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Behavior for this repeated steps?

And what about overwriting __get magic method to serve the state automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I find this irritating as well.

CWsdlGenerator uses reflection and specifically looks only for defined public properties, so it won't find magic properties like the relations.  You have to declare them as public.

But CActiveRecord uses the magic __get() function to load the relations.  And __get() isn't called for an existing public property, so if you *do* declare them, then they will never get loaded.  You would always have to explicitly load them using $model->STATE = $model->getRelated('STATE').

I thought of subclassing CWsdlGenerator and overriding processType() to check for some new doc comment to allow you to explicitly declare magic properties; but processType() is private so can't be overridden.

CWebServiceAction can be subclassed, and there you can override createWebService() to set the CWebService->generatorConfig to use a different class instead of CWsdlGenerator.  I created a copy called CWsdlGeneratorMagic and added 10 lines to parse out the doc comment.  I don't like it as a solution, but it could work.

Within my model's class doc comment (these declare the magic properties of the HAS_MANY relations 'pictures' and 'sources'):

```
/**
 * The following is for the SOAP WSDL generator replacement CWsdlGeneratorMagic
 * @magic Picture[] $pictures
 * @magic Source[] $sources
 */
```

Within my controller class:

```
/**
 * Make this a webservice
 */
public function actions() {
  return array(
    'api'=>array(
        'class'=>'CWebServiceActionMagic',
    ),
  );
}
```

within CWebServiceActionMagic.php:

```
protected function createWebService($provider,$wsdlUrl,$serviceUrl)
{
    $a = new CWebService($provider,$wsdlUrl,$serviceUrl);
    $a->generatorConfig = 'CWsdlGeneratorMagic';
    return $a;
}
```

within CWsdlGeneratorMagic (at the end of processType(), just after the closing brace of foreach($class->getProperties() as $property)):

```
// Handle magic properties
$comment = $class->getDocComment();
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/@magic\s+([\w\.]+(\[\s*\])?)\s*?(.*)$/mi', $comment, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $name = trim($match[3]);
        $name = ltrim($name, '$');
        $this->_types[$type][$name]=array($this->processType($match[1]),trim($match[3]));  // name => type, doc
    }
}
// end handling of magic properties
return 'tns:'.$type;
```

I think that it should be possible to set CWebService's generatorConfig in the application configuration file so that you wouldn't need CWebServiceActionMagic, but I couldn't get it to work.

The @magic declarations basically echo the @property ones, but only for the ones that I want exposed in the WSDL.  (Should probably call it @soapmagic or something instead).